# How to find all intersecting shapes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, spatial

I have some documents with a `location` field of `circle` kind:

```
POST /example/doc
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "circle",
        "coordinates" : [-45.0, 45.0],
        "radius" : "100m"
    }
}
```

How can I find all documents that their `location` fields intersect?

The [geoShape query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) provides the ability to find all shapes that intersect a shape provided in query. That's not what I want.

If impossible to do it in query itself, is there any solution using script?

Comment: You can consider it to query *all* locations, then query with `foreach` processor and `geoShape`

Comment: @itsho Can you please elaborate?